# How to get handle on TabSpec?

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I have a problem with my tabs. When I create a tab i can rename it and everything works. I can also delete them and Im using an ArrayList to retrieve tabs. 
However, when I delete a tab it resets the name of all of them to what it was before I rename them and this because I add them to the list before.
But there's no way I can add them to the list after because it is too late, I dont have a handle on the tab.

Any ideas on how to get the handle of TabSpecs from TabHost or something else ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

For those who will see this later; i dont know ..

I didnt get a hand on my TabSpec but instead I created another ArrayList of strings that gets filled before you delete the tab with the tab names and then when I retrieve the tabs I reassign the names without the one just deleted.

This is for the idea, you can comment if you want code or anything !